# efficient loop in R

Tags: r, loops

The data looks like

```
   cum_ft source 

 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds
 123.1018   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
   0.0000  maint 
   0.0000  maint 
   0.0000  maint 
 126.7622   imds 
 126.7622   imds 
 126.7622   imds
```

The goal is set the value for maint to the last value from imds

```
   cum_ft source 
 123.1018   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585   imds 
 125.4585  maint 
 125.4585  maint 
 125.4585  maint 
 126.7622   imds 
 126.7622   imds 
 126.7622   imds
```

I'm trying, without success, something like

```
maint_rows_to_change = which(temp_df$source=="maint")
diff_maint_row_to_change = diff(maint_rows_to_change)
imds_rows_with_data = which(temp_df$source=="imds")
diff_imds_row_to_change = diff(imds_rows_with_data)
rows_to_change_increment = which(diff_update_row > 1)
```

At this point, diff_maint_row_to_change has numbers greater than one when there are imsl data to skip over, and values of one when there are consecutive maintenance rows that have to be adjusted.  The adjustment is to set the value of cum_ft for the maintenance rows to the last value from the imsl data.

What I would like to write is something like the expression below, but I'm not clear on how to come up with last_imds_row.  In this example, maint_rows_to_change = c(11,12,13) and last_imds_row = c(10,10,10).

```
temp_df$cum_ft[maint_rows_to_change] = temp_df$cum_ft[last_imds_row]
```

I also tried a loop, with some success, but takes too long

```
fun1 <- function(z) {
  z$cum_ft_cor = z$cum_ft
  rows_to_fix = which(z$source=="maint")
  z$cum_ft_cor[rows_to_fix]=-1
  for(i in rows_to_fix) {
    z$cum_ft_cor[i] <- z$cum_ft_cor[i-1]
  }
  z
}
temp_df_2 =  fun1(temp_df)
```

Comment: Is `maint` always equals to zero while `imds` never equals to zero?

Comment: Maybe set the zeros to be `NA` and use `na.locf()`? Of course, this will depend on how the rest of your data set looks and that it is in the proper order.

Comment: There are two data sources, imds and maint.  Both the imds and maint data sources have a time stamp, but only imds has the ft_cum values.  The data above is a merge of rows from columns in the imds and maint data frames, sorted by time stamp.  The goal is to get the ft_cum value for the maint data.  So, maint is always zero, or NA, but imds can be zero or positive.  It's the maint values that have to be updated, so I just search for "maint" in the source column.

Comment: Then this is peace of cake, just do: `library(zoo) ; temp_df[temp_df$source == "maint", "cum_ft"] <- NA ; temp_df$cum_ft <- na.locf(temp_df$cum_ft)`

Comment: I like cake!!!  I'll give it a try tomorrow...  Thanks!!!

Comment: @DavidArenburg Thank you, the "loop" above takes about 90 minutes on the test case, and the na.locf approach executes almost instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to make a looping solution faster with the Rcpp package:

```
library(Rcpp)
copyDat <- cppFunction(
'void copyDat(NumericVector x, std::vector<std::string> y) {
  for (int i=1; i < y.size(); ++i) {
    if (y[i] == "maint") x[i] = x[i-1];
  }
}')
```

Then you could do:

```
copyDat(temp_df$cum_ft, as.character(temp_df$source))
temp_df
#      cum_ft source
# 1  125.4585   imds
# 2  125.4585   imds
# 3  125.4585   imds
# 4  125.4585   imds
# 5  125.4585   imds
# 6  125.4585   imds
# 7  123.1018   imds
# 8  125.4585   imds
# 9  125.4585   imds
# 10 125.4585   imds
# 11 125.4585  maint
# 12 125.4585  maint
# 13 125.4585  maint
# 14 126.7622   imds
# 15 126.7622   imds
# 16 126.7622   imds
```

On an example with 1.3 million rows, the Rcpp solution is about 6x faster than the zoo solution posted in the comments (though both are quite quick):

```
# Functions to benchmark
josilber <- function(temp_df) {
  copyDat(temp_df$cum_ft, as.character(temp_df$source))
  temp_df
}
library(zoo)
darenburg <- function(temp_df) {
  temp_df[temp_df$source == "maint", "cum_ft"] <- NA
  temp_df$cum_ft <- na.locf(temp_df$cum_ft)
  temp_df
}

# Do the test
library(microbenchmark)
temp_df <- data.frame(cum_ft=rnorm(1300000),
                      source=rep(c(rep("imds", 10), rep("maint", 3)), 100000))
all.equal(josilber(temp_df), darenburg(temp_df))
# [1] TRUE
microbenchmark(josilber(temp_df), darenburg(temp_df))
# Unit: milliseconds
#                expr       min        lq    median        uq      max neval
#   josilber(temp_df)  78.05012  83.80206  86.96831  92.56959 122.5809   100
#  darenburg(temp_df) 464.33525 492.76668 510.65864 541.43435 703.6944   100
```

Comment: I upvoted, not because it answered the question (since the comment referring to `zoo::na.locf` seemsed sufficient), but because it makes a nice skeleton for other functions that are sequential. R doesn't really provide such functions in a manner I've been able to grok, although supposedly one can use `filter`.

Comment: That's very interesting, and provides an opportunity to implement other algorithms.  In the question, there is the fun1 function that is similar to the copyDat function.  Would it be useful to add the R implementation to your benchmark table.  I didn't actually time it, I just worked on other stuff while waiting for the loop to finish.

Comment: @user3969377 `microbenchmark` is running each function 100 times, so if it really is taking 90 minutes to run your sequential code once it's probably not feasible to add it to the comparison.